# HTML code in Swift String (not NSString)

Tags: html, string, swift

I am downloading HTML source code of a webpage this way:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")
var error: NSError?
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

if (error != nil) {
    println("whoops, something went wrong")
} else {
    println(html!)
}
```

But I would like to get it as String instead of NSString. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's String also accepts the same initializer:

```
let html = String(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

I would suggest to use safe unwrapping with `if let` for your values:

```
var error: NSError?
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com"), let html = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println(html)
    }
}
```

Last note: no need to use brackets around the condition in Swift.

---

**Update for Swift 2 (Xcode 7)**

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com"),
    let html = try? String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(html)
}
```